# How to find wild card value and append to it

Tags: regex, sublime-text-2, find-and-replace, text-editing

I have part of the hundreds of lines similar to :

```
[vc_single_image image="55"]
```

How can I change the lines so they all get appended img_size="full", resulting in

```
[vc_single_image image="55" img_size="full"]
```

The problem is each instance of the image value can be any number.

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason for not just replacing ] with img_size="full"] ?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Yes because the document is littered with other ] and [ s that I don't want to touch.

Comment: You could just select `[vc_single_image image=` and then press `alt+f3` to create a cursor at every location. Then press `ctrl+right` to move behind the number and write ` image_size="full"` with every cursor. Alternatively you could use a regex search and replace.

Answer (score 2):

This worked using regex in both Notepad++ and Sublime Text 3:

Find

```
\[vc_single_image image="\d*"
```

Replace

```
$0 img_size="full"
```